# INT Inserted in SQL as NULL SSIS Package Excel to SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, ssis, int

I have setup an SSIS package to take data from an excel file, and insert it into SQL.

The package takes the data from Excel, performs some Data Conversions, and then Inserts it into my SQL DB.

One of the columns in excel contains both text, and ints.  Typically the values will be either: W2 or 1099.

In the data conversion data flow, this column is converted to: string[DT_STR], length: 50, Code Page: 1252 (ANSI - Latin I)

in SQL, the field it is going to is configured as a varchar(50).

For any row, where the column value in Excel is 1099, the data inserted into SQL, comes through as NULL.

I have no idea what could be causing this.  I have similar conversions in other packages, that come through with no issues.

i have tried formatting the column in excel as text as well as re-creating the data conversion, with no luck.

Any suggestions of ways to get this to work properly appreciated.  Please let me know if you need any additional information.

Comment: in the data conversion flow, usually, the column is named as 'Copy of Colname'. Have you mapped your SQL column to this one already?

Comment: The data conversion task changes the type from the Excel default data type of DT_WSTR to DT_STR, yes? Is there any chance you've changed the error behaviour from Fail to Ignore Failure?

Comment: @mhn yes, i can confirm I am mapping to the converted column, and not the original

Comment: @billinkc I have not changed the error behavior.  the conversion is to DT_STR, and it is from a column in excel that has mixed data types

Answer (score 0):

Is the data NULL in the Excel preview? You need to isolate whether this NULL is being provided by the Excel driver.

Anyway this sounds like the old IMEX=1 issue that has been around since forever.

http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com.au/2011/06/mixed-data-types-in-excel-column.html

Try adding IMEX=1 to your Excel connection string.